# Checking ranges for information- Double click

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro where it checks if column A,B,C ( inclusive) have information in them.  If all these  columns have information in them, it allows the user to double click in column D , which then populates with Environ("Username"). If any if these columns are blank are messgebox pops up msgbox(“Missing Information”). I have not be able to get my head around this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
        If Application.CountIf(Range("A" & Target.Row & ":C" & Target.Row), "") > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Missing Information "
        Else
            Target = Environ("Username")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

On how to add `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` see [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/beforedoubleclick-event.html).